# Count the number of records that have a given status applied to it in a specificed time period

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables matters, statuses, and matter_status

A matter belongs to many statuses and statuses belongs to many matters.

What I want to do is count the number of matters each status has in a given time period. However, I need to alter that query in order to count by the latest status a matter has rather than all statuses it has had.

For example, a matter can have a status of 'New' then a status of 'Pending' on the same day, that matter should not be included in the new count because it has a later status of pending.

This is what I have so far, but it is not returning the expected result

```php
Matter::select('id')
  ->with('statuses')
  
  ->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    $query->where('statuses.id', 1)->whereMonth('statuses.created_at', Carbon::now()->month);
})
->latest()
->count();
```

```
| matter_id | status_id | created_at          |
|-----------|-----------|---------------------|
| 1         | 1         | 2022-06-30 12:58:47 |
| 2         | 1         | 2022-06-30 12:58:47 |
| 2         | 2         | 2022-06-30 14:12:36 |
```

The matter_id = 2 has two status_ids with one created after the other.

So when counting the number of matters that have a status_id of 1 the answer should be one and not two as I only want to count the latest entry.

So I have managed to get a query returning the correct result. However, it's non-performant... 2 seconds on a table containing 8,000 rows. Here is said query:

```php
Matter::select('matters.*')
    ->join('matter_status', 'matters.id', 'matter_status.matter_id')
    ->where('matter_status.status_id', $this->status)
    ->whereBetween('matter_status.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
    ->where('matter_status.created_at', function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
            ->from('matter_status')
            ->whereColumn('matter_id', 'matters.id');
    })
    ->count();
```

Comment: can a matter be both pending and new at the same time?

Comment: No, but I need to record the history of the statuses a matter has had. But for this query, I just want to find all the matters that have a current (the last) status of new in a given time period. What is happening now is it'd counting the the new status for a matter even if it has a newer status of pending.

Comment: Did you try adding `->latest()` to the inner whereHas?

Comment: the `created_at` date though is for when a status is created the first time right? You might need a `created_at` date on the `matter_status` table as well to know when the status was associated with the matter. You can then get the latest status based on the pivot table date (either using a join order and limit or other means) Note this design means each status can only be associated to a matter once because the combination status_id/matter_id on the pivot is the key. As a sidenote: When you do `whereMonth` without also doing `whereYear` you match all entries created on that month but any year

Comment: Yes, the matter_status table has a created_at column. I want to count the number of matters for each status. If a matter has more than one status I don't want it to be counted every time only for the latest status.

Answer (score 0):

Your example query looks like it's trying to get the latest status each Matter has.  For this, you can use [`latestOfMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) (Laravel 8.42+):

```php
// Matter.php
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Status::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

This will return all matters along with their latest status:

```php
Matter::select('id')
    ->with('latestStatus')
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

However your example query is constraining when the Status itself was created, not when it got attached to the Matter.  Assuming your pivot table has timestamps, you can constrain the pivot entry using one of the [`wherePivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns) methods.

```php
Matter::select('id')
    ->with('latestStatus')
    ->whereHas('latestStatus', function ($status) {
        $status->wherePivotBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth]);
    })
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

Comment: This results in a query exception: ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'statuses.matter_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id` from `matters` where exists (select * from `statuses` inner join (select MAX(`statuses`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, `statuses`.`matter_id` from `statuses` group by `statuses`.`matter_id`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `statuses`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`matter_id` = `statuses`.`matter_id` where `matters`.`id` = `statuses`.`matter_id` and `pivot_between` = created_at) order by `created_at` desc)'```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I wanted with the following query

````
Matter::select('matters.*')
->join('matter_status', 'matters.id', 'matter_status.matter_id')
->where('matter_status.status_id', $this->status)
->whereBetween('matter_status.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
->where('matter_status.created_at',
    function ($query) { $query->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
->from('matter_status')->whereColumn('matter_id', 'matters.id'); })
->count();```
````